# Logback - C3P0 and HSQLDB

Tags: log4j, hsqldb, c3p0, logback

I'm trying to get LogBack to use a HSQLDB with C3P0. I'm stuck with this configuration at the moment given my current environment. I have a large investment with Log4J code and will also need to use the SLF4J Log4J Adapter. When I try a simple logging program it's getting stuck in the logger configuration stage.  Here is my `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
            <dataSource class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                <driverClass>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driverClass>
                <jdbcUrl>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/mid_logs</jdbcUrl>
                <user>sa</user>
                <password>sa</password>
            </dataSource>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My classpath is:

```
bin/.;lib/hsqldb.jar;lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar;lib/logback-access-0.9.17.jar;lib/logback-classic-0.9.17.jar;lib/logback-core-0.9.17.jar;lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar;lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar;lib/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
System.out.println("Starting");
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogging.class);
System.out.println("got Logger");
```

The 'Starting' appears in the console output, but nothing else.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Strip this back to basics to make sure that you can get LogBack logging to console first.  Then you can try the logging to database.

Comment: If I remove C3P0 from the mix and go with the DBAppender and direct to HSQLDB driver I get rows entered in the database. The huge problem is the HSQLDB driver doesn't re-use connections. That's why I'm trying the C3P0 connection pools.

Comment: have you tried contacting the logback-user mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

What [status messages](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#viewingStatusMessages) are you getting? You can have them listed by adding the following line in your configuraton file:

```
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
```

Since your configuration file above is not nicely formatted, making it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `StatusListener` to the `logback.xml` file and here is the output:

```
07:45:12,816 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]
07:45:12,832 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DB]
07:45:12,848 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Pushing component [connectionSource] on top of the object stack.
07:45:13,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Pushing component [dataSource] on top of the object stack.
```

If I do a "`netstat -a -n`" I see connections to the database, but no activity.